# Multiple SITE URLs for a Facebook App - possible?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login, app-id

We have a software platform with Social Logins, and Facebook is one of them. However, we at times whitel-label our domain name to the client. e.g. client.isebox.net becomes isebox.clientdomain.com

The Facebook App settings allow for, what seems, a finite (e.g. ONE) number of Site URLs - however it allows for many APP DOMAINS.

We're trying to achieve using our platform social login across all our clients without creating an appID for each new domain.

For now, I've been able to "hack" the system by adding the clients domain name into "Mobile URL"... since we don't use this field, it has accepted the clients domain name in "App Domains" since we've added it to the Mobile URL field.

This is likely an incorrect approach. In fact, certainly is. But it works. However it will not work for our next client, as there are no more URL fields available. :)

Does anyone have any tips for how our App should work and be configured if we are using our application across various domain names?

Thanks, Community!
Salvatore